# Appcelerator Titanium write custom HTTPClient

Tags: inheritance, titanium, httpclient, appcelerator

I would like to write my custom OauthClient built in on the already available Ti.Network.HTTPClient.

I've tried to inherit from it with the following code:

```
function OAuthClient (params) {

    Ti.Network.HTTPClient.call(this, params);

}

OAuthClient.prototype = Object.create(Ti.Network.HTTPClient.prototype);
OAuthClient.prototype.constructor = Ti.Network.HTTPClient;
```

but when I try to create a new OAuthClient as follows

```
var client = new OAuthClient({
    onload: function() {},
    onerror: function() {}
});
```

i got the following errors:

```
[ERROR] :  TypeError: Illegal invocation
[ERROR] :  File: app.js
[ERROR] :  Line: undefined
[ERROR] :  SourceId: undefined
[ERROR] :  Backtrace:
[ERROR] :  undefined
```

Which is the correct way to write a custom HttpClient in Titanium?

Thanks!

Comment: Haveyou tried looking into this project: https://github.com/viezel/napp.alloy.adapter.restapi

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `this` as context (`window` context), but when `HTTPClient` is called, he hopes to be executed within context of `Ti.Network`.

You can fix it changing to `Ti.Network.HTTPClient.call(Ti.Network, params)` or `var OAuthClient = Ti.Network.HTTPClient.bind(Ti.Network)`

And the `Ti.Network.HTTPClient` method will be called with expected context.

Comment: Hi, thanks but i got the same problem even changing the this context